# How to store list of tuples in Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

Is it possible to store field of tuples of `Model` in Django? In my case, I have a model Translator. The translator should store information about what languages he can translate. But there may be situation that translator can't translate from English to German but he/she can do that in opposite direction.

So one object translator could store this:

- from German to English
- from Dutch to English

but he can't translate from English to German or Dutch.

So what I probably looking for is to store field of tuples of Models (there is a model called Language).

Comment: Why do you need to store a touple when you can just store multiple columns? From-lan to-lan from-str to-str

Comment: Or, look into pickling or using JSONField. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-picklefield and https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution I recommend would be to create a model to represent each one-way translation and then use a `ManyToManyField` relationship.

For example:

```
class LanguagePair(models.Model):
   from_language = models.CharField(max_length=220)
   to_language = models.CharField(max_length=220)

class Translator(models.Model):
   languages = models.ManyToManyField('LanguagePair')
   ...
```

So each Translator would have multiple LanguagePair objects associated with it that represents the languages they can translate.

This would allow you to easily query for all Translators that can translate a particular language as the actual translation is an object. I would  also recommend that instead as storing languages in `CharField`s you actually make another `Language` model and change the `LanguagePair` model to have two `ForeignKey` fields to the language.

An alternative solution would be to serialise the list or languages pairs from a standard python list and store it as a JSON string in a `CharField` but this would make things harder for queries and could be a problem in the future. It's generally a good idea to not be afraid of separating logic out into separate models as this leads to a more flexible and scalable approach.

Comment: Thank you, this is probably a good solution but I wanted to make it as simple as possible. I choose this way. One more question - why do you put LanguagePair as a string instead of row class?

Comment: Just habit... If you use a string it can reference a model which is defined after it and you can also reference models from other apps without importing them like so: 'app.LanguagePair'. But you are correct in that example it wasn't necessary. I would also argue this *is* the simplest solution, it lets you do lookups without having to decode anything and will give you better performance. It's also more flexible for if you ever need to do anything more complex in the future.